# Repository for maven jasperreports-functions-6.1.1

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

Obviously

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

depends on jasperreports-functions, but I cannot find this in any repository. I see the jar file in Tibco Jasper Studio, I found http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases link to download the library, however we use maven in corporate environment, so I would appreciate maven repository to download the artifact automatically.

**Update**

My problem is that I can compile and run templates in Tibco Jasper studio, but I cannot compile the templates using java api

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(src, dest);
```

I'm using functions in print when expression like:

```
NOT(EQUALS($F{title}, null))
```

and getting errors when compiling in java like:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were   encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The method EQUALS(String, null) is undefined for the type sickInjuriesClosePerson_1447428912021_94804
            value =   NOT(EQUALS(((java.lang.String)field_title.getValue()), null)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                        <---->
2. The method EQUALS(String, null) is undefined for the type sickInjuriesClosePerson_1447428912021_94804
            value = NOT(EQUALS(((java.lang.String)field_firstName.getValue()), null)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=11$
                        <---->
```

At this point I'm sure it's because I'm missing jasperreports-functions-6.1.1.jar on my classpath. This file is present in jaspersoft@studio

Comment: Why "Obviously"? What did you try and what didn't work? I think you don't need this dependency for JasperReports 6.x

Comment: Well, you are right the dependency is not obvious. The jar contains report functions. If I don't use them I wouldn't need the jar. But I use NOT(EQUALS...) and getting errors like: 40. The method EQUALS(String, null) is undefined for the type sickInjuriesClosePerson_1447424887453_582349
                value = NOT(EQUALS(((java.lang.String)field_occupation.getValue()), null)); It will compile in studio but not in maven

Comment: Please update your post with the real problem you have. Post your error, what specifically doesn't compile in Maven...

Answer (score 5):

1. Add the repository

   ```
   <repository>
       <id>jr-ce-releases</id>
       <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/jr-ce-releases</url>
   </repository>
   ```
2. Add dependency to your project

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
           <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
           <version>6.6.0</version>
       </dependency>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The dependency net.sf.jasperreports should contains all the JsasperReporsts 6.1.1 functions, or simple download the jar from: 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.1

Comment: I just checked the content of the Jar file. It really contains the package file with some factory and util classes. But it's missing "standard" subpackage with functions like "LogicalFunctions", "MathFunctions" and "TextFunctions". So you are not right here